# Select dates where data is stored in plain text

Tags: mysql

My table has dates stored as:

```
August 9, 2019
September 12, 2019
etc.
```

How can I select rows where the date field value is in the next week? SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f4df7/3)

Comment: What did your research uncover thus far? Did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f4df7/3

Comment: First thing to do: Revise that schema and store dates in a date data type, not strings.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. It has to be string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DATEDIFF` and use it with `now()` function.

```
select * from table t where datediff(t.date_field,now())>7;
```

You can also use `curdate()` if you just need calculation by dates.

```
select * from table t where datediff(t.date_field,curdate())>7;
```

Since you mentioned that  your field is a string and not a datetime I'd first convert string to date using `STR_TO_DATE` and do the comparison as below :

```
select * from table where datediff(STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%M %d,%Y %h:%i%p'),curdate())>7;
```

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/242026/3)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't return any results http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f4df7/3 (In my database, I changed the date to August 26 to work with your '>7'

Comment: @Tom your date column should be of type `datetime` for the comparison not string.

Comment: Edited the answer with SQL Fiddle

Comment: Can it work with longtext? Unfortunately it's a WP meta field so it stores all kinds of data in that column.  The example I'm working on just happens to be a date

Comment: @Tom you can use same function after converting the string to date. Updated your fiddle in answer.

Comment: @Tom Please add that information to your question. Make your question as detailed as possible.